# SQL - Where like statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a table with two columns (id, numberslist).

How can I get all rows that have exactly "**1**" in numberslist (in this case id = 2)

Whats the sql statement?

---

id | numberslist

1 | 11,111
2 | 1,2,3

---

This doesnt work:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytabelle WHERE numberslist LIKE '%1%'";
```

I know it's a bad database design to list all numbers in this way but its not changeable.

Comment: I'm sorry you're stuck with this schema.

Comment: Wow, agree with @Joe and others. Terrible schema.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MySQL supports "word boundary" patterns in its [regular expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) syntax for this purpose.

```
WHERE numberlist REGEXP '[[:<:]]1[[:>:]]'
```

You could alternatively use [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1', numberlist) > 0
```

That said, I agree with comments in other answers that storing a comma-separated list in a string like this is not good database design.  See my answer to [Is storing a comma separated list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-comma-separated-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)

Comment: +1 thanks for the into to the Find_In_Set function. Sadly, I'm going to find that useful.

Comment: This answer summarizes why Bill has 94k points and I have only 763 points :D +1 for the nice answer, I totally forgot about regex and FIND_IN_SET

Comment: Nice find, Bill.  To the OP -- long as you stay in MySQL, this is a good solution. :)

Answer (score 4):

The design is really bad. Anyways, for this bad design, this bad code should do the work :D

```
SELECT * FROM mytabelle WHERE numberslist = '1' OR
                              numberslist LIKE '%,1' OR 
                              numberslist LIKE '%,1,%' OR 
                              numberslist LIKE '1,%';
```

Comment: +1 for covering bases. Lets hope there aren't any spaces though :-)

Answer (score 3):

For this specific case, you could do something like:

```
WHERE numberslist = '1' OR numberslist LIKE '1,%' OR numberslist LIKE '%,1,%' OR numberslist LIKE %,1'";
```

assuming there's no whitespace between numbers and commas.

But that's ugly, not to mention will be unable to use any kind of indexing at all.

Answer (score 2):

You should read about table normalization. Here's a good [introduction](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/c0004752.htm).